# Neither onCommand nor onClick work

Tags: xul

I've got such `XUL` form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<window xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" height="300" id="hello" width="300">
<groupbox>
    <caption label="Calculator"/>
    <grid>
        <columns>
            <column/>
        </columns>
        <rows>
            <row>
                <hbox>
                    <textbox flex="1" id="input"/>
                </hbox>
            </row>
            <row>
                <hbox>
                    <button id="1" label="1" onCommand="alert('Hello world 1!');"/>
                    <button id="2" label="2" onCommand="alert('Hello world 2!');"/>
                    <button id="3" label="3" onCommand="alert('Hello world 3!');"/>
                </hbox>
            </row>
            <row>
                <hbox>
                    <button id="4" label="4" onCommand="alert('Hello world 4!');"/>
                    <button id="5" label="5" onCommand="alert('Hello world 5!');"/>
                    <button id="6" label="6" onCommand="alert('Hello world 6!');"/>
                </hbox>
            </row>
            <row>
                <hbox>
                    <button id="7" label="7" onCommand="alert('Hello world 7!');"/>
                    <button id="8" label="8" onCommand="alert('Hello world 8!');"/>
                    <button id="9" label="9" onCommand="alert('Hello world 9!');"/>
                </hbox>
            </row>
            <row>
                <hbox>
                    <button label="0"/>
                    <button label="C"/>
                    <button label="="/>
                </hbox>
            </row>
        </rows>
    </grid>
</groupbox>
</window>
```

But when I click any button - nothing happens. If I set `onClick` instead of `onCommand` - it doesn't work either.

I use Mozilla Remote XUL and XULExplorer to test my application. But it doesn't work there.

What's the problem?

P.S I've installed old version of mozilla browser - and it doesn't work there either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved!

I used `onCommand` instead of `oncommand`